# jQuery slider filtering values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to filter some text based on the attribute data-length. For example if the slider is in between the value 15 and 20, I want all the  tags to be displayed where the data-length is between these two values and hide the all those that have in the data-length more than 20 or less than 15.

Here is a link what I tried so far but was not successful:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/g0dwpzha/22/)

the jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
  $('#slider-container').slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    values: [0, 20],
    create: function() {
      $("#value").val("0 - 20");
    },
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#value").val(" " + ui.values[0] + " - " + ui.values[1]);
      var mi = ui.values[0];
      var mx = ui.values[1];
      filterSystem(mi, mx);
    }
  })
});

function filterSystem(minPrice, maxPrice) {
  $("#computers div.match js-match").hide().filter(function() {
    var price = parseInt($(this).data("data-length"), 10);
    return price >= minPrice && price <= maxPrice;
  }).show();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code there is no #computers id, so your selector won't run. You also do not have a div with the class match nor do you have a js-match node.

I would change your selector from `#computers div.match js-match` to `em.match.js-match`

You can also get the data length by using `.attr('data-length')`, or `.data('length')`

The result would be:

```
$("em.match.js-match").hide().filter(function () {
    var price = parseInt($(this).data("length"), 10);
    return price >= minPrice && price <= maxPrice;
}).show();
```

Comment: May I ask also what else do I change to make this  `values: [0, 20],` with only one `value: 20` , so that for example when I put the slider at 20 to get those with `.attr('data-length')` below 20.

Comment: you would probably want to change `range: "max"`, having `value: 20`; then you could pass `ui.value` to your `filterSystem`, then have `return price <= ui.value`
[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/749st2w5/)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Also change your selector from `$("#computers div.match js-match")` to just `$(".js-match")`

You would simply use `$(this).data("length")` instead of `$(this).data("data-length")`

Comment: okay, I tried, but not working, it's displaying both the one with 12 and 22 when the slider is between 10 and 15

Comment: Edited the answer, check now